# ARM Templates - Explain "reference: {}" property under parameters section

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have seen examples like this:

```
....
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
  "keyVaultSecretValue": {
    "reference": { <===========  Reference property
      "keyVault": {
        "id": "...."
      },
      "secretName": "...."
    }
  }
},
....
```

I can't find any documentation on possible usages of this `reference` property.

#### Would I be able to use it for eg: Referencing a linkedTemplate's output variables?

As such:

`[reference('sqlServerLinkedTemplate').outputs.connectionString.value]`

Or other kind of references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example at the top, `reference` refers to the Key Vault you want to add the secret to. An example of this is shown here:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "adminLogin": {
        "value": "exampleadmin"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
        "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name>"
        },
        "secretName": "ExamplePassword"
        }
    },
    "sqlServerName": {
        "value": "<your-server-name>"
    }
}
}
```

Linking templates together is done by either nesting templates together or by linking them together. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates) has great information on this.

An example of a linked template is shown below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
        "name": "linkedTemplate",
        "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri":"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.json",
            "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
        }
        }
    }
    ],
    "outputs": {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a bit confused. Is the "reference" property used ONLY for keyvault purposes and CANNOT be used for referencing anything else?

Comment: In the example you provided, it is used to reference the Key Vault where the secret needs to go. It could be that in another resource type, reference is used for something else. The template reference is very good and is like your bible for developing templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/